# getting error #1242 while deleting data from the table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to delete data from the table and my query is as below:

```
delete from mybadge where uid=5 and badge_name=(select concat(tag_name,'-Beginner') from tag,post_tags where post_tags.tag_id=tag.tag_id);
```

I am getting 5 records by select statement, I want to delete all that 5 records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use- **'in'** keyword instead of **'='** sign

```
delete from mybadge where uid=5 and badge_name in (select concat(tag_name,'-Beginner') from tag,post_tags where post_tags.tag_id=tag.tag_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sub-query, as you stated, returns 5 rows. 
However, the badge_name cannot have 5 different values in the same row. It's a bit like saying:

```
 delete from mybadge where uid=5 and badge_name=(5 different values)
```

try

```
delete from mybadge where uid=5 and badge_name in (select concat(tag_name,'-Beginner') from tag,post_tags where post_tags.tag_id=tag.tag_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the select statement is working fine for you then just delete all uid's returned by the select:

```
DELETE FROM mybadge WHERE uid IN(
SELECT uid
FROM mybadge 
WHERE uid=5 
AND badge_name=(SELECT concat(tag_name,'-Beginner') 
                FROM tag,post_tags 
                WHERE post_tags.tag_id=tag.tag_id)
);
```